# boost::asio::strand wrap causing shared_ptr from shared_from_this to become NULL

Tags: c++, boost-asio

When I tried to use `boost::asio::strand` `wrap` function, it seems to cause the `shared_ptr` that came from `shared_from_this` to become NULL, so when it is executed the second time, it will cause the program to crash.

However, this only happens if the function that was binded takes **no arguments**.

After setting the watch point and checking the callstack, this behavior seems to be caused by move constructor of `shared_ptr` swapping value, which originated from `async_result_init` with `BOOST_ASIO_MOVE_CAST`.

My question is, how should I properly use `wrap` to avoid this from happening?

Below is a simple sample to show you what I meant:

```
class object : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<object> {
public:
    object()
    : service(new boost::asio::io_service),
    work(new boost::asio::io_service::work(*service)),
    strand(*service),
    value(0) {}

    void workerThread() {
        service->run();
    }

    void run() {
        func_int = strand.wrap(boost::bind(&object::handler_int, shared_from_this(), _1));
        func_void = strand.wrap(boost::bind(&object::handler_void, shared_from_this()));

        std::thread thread(boost::bind(&object::workerThread, this));

        func_int(1);
        func_int(1);

        func_void();
        func_void();    // Will crash due to shared_ptr being NULL, hence "value" cannot be accessed in handler_void

        thread.join();
    }

    void handler_int(int parameter) {
        cout << "handler_int: " << value << endl;
    }

    void handler_void() {
        cout << "handler_void: " << value << endl;
    }

    boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service> service;
    boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work> work;
    boost::asio::strand strand;
    std::function<void(int)> func_int;
    std::function<void(void)> func_void;
    int value;
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {    
    boost::shared_ptr<object> obj(new object());
    obj->run();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you're not initialising the work object correctly.

Comment: @RichardHodges: Thank you for your reply, but I am not sure if that is the cause. I have seen `work` initialized this way too: [link](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/services/logger_service.hpp)

Comment: understood. It's poor style but the real answer is below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to a misunderstanding of what `wrap` does. This caught me out too recently. I wrote to the author of asio for clarification. What he told me surprised me.

`wrap` returns a 'wrapped_handler' but contrary to what you might expect, **this is not a function object which performs a dispatch under the covers**.

It is actually an object that contains the handler you bound plus a reference to the executor. Asio io objects use this information when completing async operations in order to execute the handler in the correct context.

Confusingly, this `wrapped_handler` also has an `operator()`. What this does is merely execute the bound function. It does *not* post or dispatch the function. In my view this `operator()` should not exist. I have mailed Christopher Kohlhoff expressing this view. I have not had a reply.

you can prove this by replacing this:

```
func_int(1);
```

with this:

```
service->post(strand->wrap(boost::bind(&object::handler_int, shared_from_this(), 1)));
```

for each of the invocations of the bound member function. You can then test that they are executing *in the strand*.

Note that it would not matter which `io_service` you posted/dispatched them to. They would be sent straight to the strand with which they have been associated by `wrap`.

Finally, on asio and style.

You may want to address the ownership of io_service/strand/work objects by shared_ptr. This is always un-necessary. An io_service is a fundamental component of an application - the central message loop. It will not have an indeterminate lifetime. Neither will the work or the strand. Provided you end its lifetime with:

```
service.stop();
thread(s).join();
```

All will be well.

Comment: Thank you for such detailed explanation.

However, when I was debugging, looking at the object structure at break point, I did kind of guessed it was a wrapper around original function, as I did see the `dispatcher_` and `handler_` member variables. Also in memory, the address of my original `object` pointer appeared more than once.

What I wanted to know is why it differs when argument count differs, and how to properly use `wrap`.

Comment: As for `service->post...`, I have tested it, and if I create a second service and call `service2->post`, the function will be called in the service2 (checked with thread ID), not the `strand` it was associated to, since in your example, you did not call it with the `strand`.

Comment: As far as I know, io_service cannot be copied, so to make sure it can be passed around, you wrap it around a shared_ptr, so it is not really un-necessary from my point of view.

Comment: @Bill: pass reference, store reference.  In some cases, you might need  `std::ref` and the related class.

Comment: @Bill. create the io_service in main(). pass it by reference everywhere.

Comment: @Bill. sorry - updated the example code. now goes through the strand.

Comment: @RichardHodges: Ok, understood